# While loop, value k will not increment

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

The value K is set to increment depending on i in order to evaluate l1, l2, l3, l4 until k<= g.  What am I doing wrong????

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)  {

    float  c=0, h=0, x=0, i=0;

    printf("Proj. #2 - Juan Perez\n");
    printf("Power of lamps (in watts)?  ");
    scanf("%f" , &c);

    printf("Height of lamp (in meters)?  ");
    scanf("%f" , &h);

    printf("Distance apart? (in meters)?  ");
    scanf("%f" , &x);

    printf("Interval? (in meters)? ");
    scanf("%f" , &i);


    printf("Power: %f\n", c);
    printf("Height: %f\n",  h);
    printf("Distance apart: %f\n",  x);
    printf("Interval: %f\n",  i);

    float  k=75, d=0, e=x, f=2*x, g=3*x;
    float  l1=((c*h)/(powf((h*h)+((k-d)*(k-d)), 1.5)));
    float  l2=((c*h)/(powf((h*h)+((k-e)*(k-e)), 1.5)));
    float  l3=((c*h)/(powf((h*h)+((k-f)*(k-f)), 1.5)));
    float  l4=((c*h)/(powf((h*h)+((k-g)*(k-g)), 1.5)));
    float j=l1+l2+l3+l4;

    while (k<=g){
        printf("%f\n", j);
        k+=i;
    }

}
```

Comment: You say "until k<=g" but your code has "while k<=g". I'm assuming your code is correct here but you should be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

since k = 75, and g = 0, since the condition is never true, that loop will never execute, and the print statement will not work, and the incrementation of k will never happen either.

change

```
while (k<=g){
```

to

```
while (k>=g){
```

To watch it fly out of control (run in an infinite loop), since k will always be greater than g.

Comment: FWIW, `g` is set to `3*x` before the loop, but unless `x` is greater than 25 the same principles apply.

Comment: g is 3 times whatever x input is.  I meant to change k starting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend incrementing a while loop with floats.

Here is a link to why: [Any risk of using float variables as loop counters and their fractional increment/decrement for non "==" conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595668/any-risk-of-using-float-variables-as-loop-counters-and-their-fractional-incremen)

Also g is set to zero and never updated.